# Error al registrar en Oracle desde JAVA Netbeans

Tags: java, oracle

Buenas tardes amigos tengo un problema con una aplicación que estoy desarrollando, es algo sencilla.
Al registrar una persona en mi Base de datos de Oracle.

1. Esa Es mi clase Conexion.

   ```
   public Connection xconecta(){

   try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
       con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","SYSTEM","12marzo1996");

           if (con!=null)
           {
               System.err.println("CONECTADO");
           }
           else
           {
               System.err.println("Error");
           }
       return con;
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
       System.err.println(e.getMessage());
       return null;
   }
   }
   ```
2. Con este metodo Registro mi persona.

   ```
   public void INGRESAR(){
           try {
             pst=con.xconecta().prepareStatement("insert into EJEMPLO 
             values(?,?,?)");
             pst.setInt(1, 1);
             pst.setString(2, "Jose");
             pst.setString(3, "Castillo");
             pst.execute();
               } catch (SQLException e)
               {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

            }
   ```
3. Al Ejecutar esto Me aparece el mensaje que se pudo conectar a la BD, pero no inserta nada. Pero el programa sigue corriendo.
   Lo probe en Sql Server y si funciona correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No te arroja ninguna excepción eso indica que por parte de la aplicación va todo bien, revisa tu estructura en la base de datos, yo trabajo con similar estructura y me funciona bien.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día

Acabo de realizar una prueba con el driver ojdbc7.jar en una base de datos Oracle 11g y el jdk 8 y funciona perfecto. Prueba cambiando los drivers.

Además, veo raro esta parte:

```
pst=con.xconecta().prepareStatement("insert into EJEMPLO 
          values(?,?,?)");
```

xconecta retorna un objecto tipo Connection. No entiendo que es con en tu contexto.

Saludos

Comment: gracias ... aclarando el valor "con" es como llame a mi clase Conexión al instanciarla en esa parte, y mi función para conectar con la BD  se llama xconecta.